# How to increase number of preloaded UITableView cells in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I was wondering if it is possible to increase the number of preloaded UITableView cells.

The problem is, I have webviews in table cells and when you scroll down, they first show empty screen then load the page. Which doesn't look good.

I thought maybe I can solve this by loading more cells off the screen, so they appear more smoothly.

What do you think about this, is it possible?

Comment: you can use tableview will display cell to load data earlier help

Comment: you should probably restructure how you are calling the webservices then, shouldnt do it in the cell, but as part of the viewcontroller of something, then download cell.count + x number of whatever

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to preload more cells. Instead create a data source implementation that fetches more data.